# motion vectors in an mpeg video

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to extract the motion vectors directly from an mpeg video.

I have found that there are two parammeters, the dc and ac. The dc image called the image energy and the ac image called the texture and edge map. Then, the motion vectors exits in p and b frame.

What is the relation between the ac,dc coefficients of the dct and the motion vectors and how it can be extracted from an mpeg video ?

Comment: Do you mean "I went" or "I want"? This question is much too vague to be answered, although slightly more clear than your [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450167/dynamic-textures-model). Maybe you can tell us where you got the info you already have from (about ac/dc etc.), and what is unclear about these sources?

Comment: Why do you want motion vectors ?